# stacked Bi-LSTM compare to 1 layer of Bi-LSTM

Tags: keras, nlp, lstm

I trained my model on BI LSTM for multi class text classification, but my result is not different when I use 2 stacked  BI LSTM like below compare to just 1 layer of BI LSTM, any idea about that ?

```
max_len = 409
max_words = 17666
emb_dim = 100


BB = Sequential()
BB.add(Embedding(max_words, emb_dim,weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_len))
BB.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True,dropout=0.4, recurrent_dropout=0.4)))
BB.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(34, return_sequences=False,dropout=0.4, recurrent_dropout=0.4)))

BB.add(Dropout(0.5))
BB.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

BB.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
BB.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be the issue is that your embeddings dimension is quite low a(100), maybe you could try some other embedding type as text representation, like word2vec, which has an embedding dimension of 300, if I am not mistaken.
On the modeling side, would try experimenting with increasing LSTM units first (try 100 or more), then stacking LSTM layers on top of each other.
I also, noticed that your model is very heavily regularized through Dropout, recurrent and otherwise. Did you notice overfitting while training your model? If not, I would suggest removing those as they can affect training if unnecessarily added.